# Is there a Kotlin Coroutines Channel equivalent of RxJava's onDispose?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

If I extend an `Observable<>` in RxJava, I can override `OnDispose()`, and perform cleaning up such as clearing things for the Garbage Collector.

`OnDispose()` is called whenever any subscription to this `Observable<>` is disposed of.

However, I can't seem to find anything equivalent for Coroutine Channels.

I am aware of channel.close(), but that is not the same.

Is there some way to propagate either

- suspended coroutine cancellation to the Channel; or
- subscription disposal/cancellation to the Channel?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you talking about `doOnDispose` in RxJava. In this case you are sending elements to the channel and would like to know when the downstream had [cancelled](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-receive-channel/cancel.html) the channel. If you structure your producing code in a single function, then you can simply use `try/finally`:

```
val channel = produce { 
    // channel producing code is here
    try {
        // this example is sending 10 ints, but it can be any other code
        repeat(10) { send(it) }
    } finally {
        // doOnDispose here!
    }
}
```

If your sending code is spread-out and you'd like to receive a cancellation *callback* then you can use [SendChannel.invokeOnClose](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/invoke-on-close.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm afraid I'm referring to dispose(), not doOnDispose(). I can't find documentation, but you can see it being overridden here:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding3/view/ViewClickObservable.kt#L54

That link also shows a use-case similar to mine.

Comment: I missed the invokeOnClose() comment below. That seems to operate in a similar way, but not in the way I'm expecting. Once I have reproducible code I'll probably log a new question